# Spring actuator metrics not visible from JMX console from 2.2.0 release onwards

Tags: java, windows, macos, spring-boot-actuator

The simplest spring boot app created using start.spring.io, without no further changes to it. 3 dependencies are added `spring-boot-starter-actuator, spring-boot-starter-web and spring-boot-devtools`.

Spring Boot 2.4.0, 2.2.0 - org.springframework.boot metrics not visible

Spring Boot 2.1.0 or previous release - works

Behavior is same in jdk 11 and 15, macOS Catalina and windows.

['/actuator' path is accessible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZUb1.png)

[But org.springframework.boot metrics not visible from JConsole or VisualVM when connected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJKbJ.png)

What could it be for for significant change of behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Added "micrometer-registry-jmx" dependency explicitly

Comment: I had kinda the same problem: I had "micrometer-registry-jmx" but was lacking "spring-boot-starter-actuator" for my non-web application (WebApplicationType.NONE). Seems like without actuators, no JMX metrics are computed.

Answer (score 0):

add this lib in pom.xml and metrics will be exposed to JMX in a formatted way, you can see a domain in jconsole called metrics you will find your metrics under it.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
        <artifactId>micrometer-registry-jmx</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.4</version>
    </dependency>
```